# Noetherian Chevalley's theorem on constructible sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do you prove the following theorem due to Chevalley?
I think a few books(for example EGA) prove this theorem,
but it is nice to have a detailed proof of it here.
To state the theorem, we need the following definition.

**Definition**
Let $X$ be a topological space.
A subset of $X$ is called quasi-constructible if it is a finite union of locally closed subsets.

**Noetherian Chevalley's Theorem**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of finite type of schemes.
Suppose $Y$ is noetherian.
Let $Z$ be a quasi-constructible subset of $X$.
Then $f(Z)$ is a quasi-constructible subset of $Y$.

Comment: Why should we reprove it here when, as you say, it is in several books? There are multiple ways to do this. One is using Grothendieck's generic freeness lemma (this is how it is done in Vakil), other's use more elementary techniques (see Lei Fu's book on Etale Cohomology).

Comment: @AlexYoucis I had not known that Vakil's book has the proof. I don't have Lei Fu's book. I don't have an easy access to a university library, either. Regards.

Comment: If you google "Lei Fu etale cohomology" the fourth link is a copy of the book.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm afraid it's an illegal copy. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261114/hartshorne-exercise-ii-3-19-c).